# nodejs json-schema fail to read schema

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, jsonschema

I have an express app, which has a post method(the post is a json type):

server.js(simplified version):

```
   app.post('/listener/v1/event/', function(req, res) {
            .
            .
            var event = req.body;
            var validator = require("./validator");
            validator.validate(event);
    }
```

validator.js contains the validation for the json:

```
var jsonschemavalidate = require("json-schema");
var basicSchema = require('fs').readFileSync('./schema.json', 'utf8');

exports.validate = function (event) {
    console.log(jsonschemavalidate.validate(event, basicSchema).errors);
}
```

The schema.json:

```
{ 
    name : "test",
    type : 'object', 
    properties : { 
        event_id : { type : 'string' }, 
        timestamp : { type : 'string' } 
    }
}
```

For the input I use curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"event_id": "NedaleGassss", "timestamp": "a2009321"}' http://localhost:3000/listener/v1/event/
```

The output is as follows:

```
[ { property: '',
    message: 'Invalid schema/property definition {\n    name : "test",\n    type : "object",\n    additionalProperties : false,\n    properties :\n    {\n        event_id            : { type : "string" },\n        timestamp        \t: { type : "string" }\n    }\n}' } ]
```

Comment: How do they fail? I.e. what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: @jsalonen I added the input and output

Comment: It looks like you are passing a string to the validator and It should be JSON. Looking at the test in the json-schema project you can see that they use JSON.parse(str) before calling validate. 
https://github.com/kriszyp/json-schema/blob/master/test/tests.js

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is invalid, as the error says. The schema should also be valid JSON,
so properties and strings should be double quoted:

```
{ 
  "name" : "test",
  "type" : "object", 
  "properties"  : { 
    "event_id"  : { "type" : "string" }, 
    "timestamp" : { "type" : "string" } 
  }
}
```

This should do the trick, (unless you figured it out already in the past year)

And also:

```
var basicSchema = require('fs').readFileSync('./schema.json', 'utf8');
```

could probably be replaced by:

```
var basicSchema = require('./schema');
```